# What properties of the real numbers are almost always true and there are no (or very few) known examples of?

Tags: real-numbers, big-list

What properties of the positive real numbers 
are almost always true 
and there are no (or very few) known examples of?

Two that come to mind are
numbers that are normal in every base
and
numbers satisfying Khinchine's theorem
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant).

So I wondered
what other properties
are like this.

Comment: But it is not always always true that a number is normal in every base... Perhaps you meant "almost always"?

Comment: The [non-computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number#Countable_but_not_computably_enumerable) come to mind.

Comment: @TonyK: Yup. That was a typo on my part. Don't know what it says about the deterioration of my brain.

Comment: Incidentally, it is **not** true that no examples of absolutely normal numbers are known: many have been constructed, see e.g. https://math.berkeley.edu/~slaman/papers/poly.pdf. Of course these are not *mathematically natural* examples (such as $\pi, \sqrt{2}, e$, which we suspect are absolutely normal), but then "almost all" numbers aren't, too. :) And @DanielR it depends - there are definable non-computable reals (such as Chaitin's constant), so I'm not sure that fits.

Comment: There is only one prime number that is even ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one I like: almost all numbers fail to be [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number).  In particular, there are only countably many finite, terminating algorithms, and consequently there are only countably many real numbers that can be expressed (to arbitrary precision) via such algorithms.

One example of a non-computable number is [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

Comment: how much clearer and more interesting would the philosophy of mathematics have been if, in the definition "a real number is one that can be expressed as an infinite decimal", the "can" was taken to be an *effective* "can", so that real numbers were by definition the computable numbers...

Comment: @VladimirSotirov yes, then we could make [every function continuous](http://math.andrej.com/2006/03/27/sometimes-all-functions-are-continuous/)

Answer (score 3):

Almost always still allows for an infinite yet uncountable amount to get through see [Cantor Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) for an example on how to build such sets.

Another more trivial example would be the number is not an integer or the number is not of this "particular" countable set whatever that set may be.

Other things that come to mind are things like [Zigmondys theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) which states that in the series $2^n-1$ the only number to not contain a new prime factor is $n=6, 2^6-1 =63$.

Comment: (2^9)-1 = 256-1=255 >> I probably missed the point you made.

Comment: 255's prime factorization is 3*5*17, the Theorem is at least 3 or 5 or 17 has not shown up in the prime factorization of any number previously. in this case 17

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer sorry I forgot to tag you in my reply.

Comment: Never heard of  Zigmondy's theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @shaihorowitz -thanks! great to learn something new and simple (once I get it).